# Java method will not execute multiple times

Tags: java, methods, method-call

I'm trying to get the method printMethod to execute 6 times for 6 different inputs, but it takes one input, outputs the result once and then ends. I have tried positioning the method calls in different locations but it doesn't seem  to make any difference. Could someone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Lab_Week4_PrintTable_Part2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)   {

        printMethod();
        printMethod();
        printMethod();
        printMethod();
        printMethod();
        printMethod();

        }

        private static void printMethod() {
            Scanner data = new Scanner (System.in);
            String output = data.nextLine();
            System.out.println("---------------------");     
            System.out.println("|   |   |   |   |   |");
            System.out.println(output);
            System.out.println("|   |   |   |   |   |");     
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            data.close();
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to closing the `Scanner` that was opened using `System.in`.

`System.in` is opened by the JVM and if you forcefully close it when you close the `Scanner`, you will find yourself unable to open it again for the remainder of the program.

Simply remove the line `data.close()`, and suppress warnings for the `Scanner` if you do not want to see the warning and your program will work as expected.

Typically you do not want to close the `Scanner` that is using `System.in` in the future, and `System.in` will be closed automatically anyway, so do not worry about it.

Note that you **should** close `Scanner` if you opened it using a `File` instead of `System.in`.

Comment: In anycase OP should only have a single `Scanner` and not redeclare / reinstantiate it everytime the method is called and just reuse that object

Comment: @Frakcool Yeah that is true, however, perhaps this is meant to be a standalone method that is not dependent on any outside interaction, which I could see reason for wanting it declared inside the method.  Depending on the goal here, both could have a reason.

Comment: I agree on that @Nexevis

Comment: This worked, much appreciated. I had thought previously that it was bad practice to leave a scanner open but it seems that sometimes it is necessary to leave it open

Comment: @Charlie Understandable mistake to make, I think in a classroom setting they don't usually explain specifics on closing and just say _always_ to close it, which is _usually_ true.